# How can I manipulate the user input from a Blazor form and then send the values using my model format (JSON)?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm writing a Blazor web app and once I get the user input using a web form by following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#example-form-1. I'm wondering how can I grab all the values from the form covert them to JSON and then send an HTTP post to an endpoint with this JSON payload?

```
private async Task HandleValidSubmit()
{

    var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

    try
    {
        starship = await client.PostAsync(uri, HttpContent startship);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errorString = "there was an error";
    }

}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. how to manipulate user input

if you follow the link mentioned in your question you will notice that a startship is a private object and it is referenced in the EditForm as Model Parameter of the component, then the user can change the values of that object.

2. send the values:

You can use PostAsJsonAsync from System.Net.Http.Json to send the C# object as JSON.

```
client.PostAsJsonAsync(uri,startship)
```